# How to use C# to connect to Exchange Server via RPC Over HTTPs

Tags: c#, winforms, exchange-server, email, email-client

We have application implemented in WinForm. Now Customer requests to add new feature - Mail Function. That one i have to connect to customer mail server (Exchange Server) to send marketing email. They are using RPC Over HTTPS with Outlook Client to connect to Exchange Server. They asked me to refer this link http://www.msexchange.org/tutorials/outlookrpchttp.html

That all I know. When they asked, I even don't know what is RPC Over HTTPS. But after I did searching on Internet I understand a bit now. I really need a code sample for this problem.

Please advise me.

Thank you all a lot.
Regards,

Answer (score 0):

What are you using to send messages now?
If you are using the Outlook Object Model or Extended MAPI to send using an existing Outlook profile, there is nothing you need to do - that will all happen under the hood.